# How long does a visa ban last when you are blacklisted for business visa violations by FRRO or MHA India?

Tags: visa-refusals, india, visa-bans

I had a 3-year Indian business visa, which expired in November 2019. I was banned from India in February 2019 after I applied for a Residential Permit and left India on an Exit Permit with the remark: FURTHER VISA EXTENSION DENIED FOR NOT FULFILLING/CONFIRMING TO BUSINESS VISA
NORMS.

Only later, I learned that a 'Ban Entry Look Out Circular' was issued about me and that I was blacklisted by the Foreigners Regional Registration Officer (FRRO), Chennai.

I filed a court complaint against the decision, but that case is still pending, and neither my lawyer nor any official, not even the Indian Mission in The Netherlands, can tell me how long a 'Ban Entry Look Out Circular’ will last and how long I will stay on the blacklist.

Does anybody know where I can get or find this information?

Comment: I edited the third paragraph of your question, to make clear that the duration information you seek cannot be found by your lawyer or the Foreign Indian Mission in the Netherlands. If you disagree with my changes, you can revert my edits by using the "edit" button below the question text.

Comment: You can ask your lawyer who I assume is an Indian citizen to file an RTI application (right to information) which only Indian citizens can apply for to get more detailed information and duration of the ban. The concerned department will provide information within 30 days.

Answer (score 2):

You can read more about the LOC here in this [Ministry of Home Affairs site](https://www.mha.gov.in/PDF_Other/Lookoutcircular_27042017.pdf).

First point of this circular says

> For the future, it is considered that whenever any authority issues a warning circular to the immigration authorities, the period of validity should be clearly specified in the circular. If this is not done, the circular will be considered to be valid only for a period of one year from the date of issue and a watch will be maintained by the person concerned at the immigration check posts only for that period.